# How to make html content in a WebView fit the width of the screen?

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying to display some html content (received from a a web service so I have no control on it) in a `WebView` and I cannot get it to fit the width of the screen, with no horizontal scrolling (normal text size and images wider than the screen resized to fit the screen width).

The image is quite large: 1000 x 1000px.

I have `minSdkVersion 15` and `targetSdkVersion 19` and testing on Nexus 4 with 4.4.4.

How can I achieve that? Below is everything I've tried from solutions found on the internet.

```
String html = "<p><b>bla bla bla> ... <p><figure class=\"module images
    non-editable full\"><img class=\"full\" title=\"Image title\"
    src=\"\/assets\/theimage.jpg\" alt=\"bla bla \">
    <figcaption>bla bla<\/figcaption><\/figure><\/p>";

WebView webview = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

**test 1**

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(Config.URL_ROOT, html, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

The text size is ok, but the image is not resized and I have to scroll horizontally to see it all.

**test 2**

```
webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(Config.URL_ROOT, html, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Same as test 1.

**test 3**

```
webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(Config.URL_ROOT, html, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Same as test 1.

**test 4**

```
webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(Config.URL_ROOT, html, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Tiny text, image less wide than in test 1, but still wider than the screen.

**test 5**

```
html = "<!DOCTYPE html>" +
            "<html>" +
            "<head>" +
            "<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, user-scalable=no'/>" +
            "<title>Viewport Test</title>" +
            "</head>" +
            "<body style=\"margin: 0px;\">" +
            "<div>" +
            html +
            "</div>" +
            "</body>" +
            "</html>";

webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(Config.URL_ROOT, html, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Same as test 1, though according to the [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html#Viewport):

```
"(this) <meta> tag specifies that the viewport width should exactly match the
device screen's width and that the ability to zoom should be disabled"
```

Comment: your <img> tag specifies class="full", yet there are no CSS styles defined?  Try <img style="width:100%;" .../> along with your test 5 code

Comment: For some reason with width=100% the image is smaller than the screen width, but still better than having to horizontally scroll, so I'll do that. Thanks.